# disable pop up notification in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I wrote this code for disable pop up window:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url="https://www.fluidmeet.com/search/Dubai/office-spaces"
driver.get(url)
```

But it's not working!
This picture show that pop up window:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code wouldn't do anything with element pop-up in DOM.

In your case pop-up is rendered on load in DOM (no Chrome option can disable it) and after some time it receives class 'show-flex', so it becomes visible for you at random time that defined by site logic / your actions.

Dealing with such pop-up is some kind of reverse engineering and specific for every case.

As a general suggestion, I suggest to find for element pop-up and remove it from DOM after load, using native JS `remove` function.

In current case your popup unique selector is element that has classes `more-filter fz-17 justify-content-center` and has child element `.popup-send-requests`.

```py
driver.get('https://www.fluidmeet.com/search/Dubai/office-spaces')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.execute_script("""
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("[class*='more-filter fz-17 justify-content-center']");
    
    elements.forEach(element => {
      if (!!element.querySelector('.popup-send-requests')) {
        element.remove();
        console.log('Removed');
      }
    });
""")

search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#srch-btn")))
```

Comment: Yes, yes, it worked! Thank you so much for always helping me